# Error: Use of \@index doesn't match its definition

Tags: macros, labels, indexing, nesting, hyperlink

First, let me show you something that works. It creates a link from an indexed term to its corresponding entry in the index, and vice-versa.

```
\newcommand{\myname}[2]{#1\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#2}}  % #1 is index entry; #2 is entry in the text

\begin{document}
\ref{314}\index{\myname{decision tree}{decision trees}\label{314}}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to automate this and write a macro called `Index`. I came up with this:

```
\newcommand{\myname}[2]{#1\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#2}}  % #1 is index entry; #2 is entry in the text
\newcommand{\Index}[2]{\index{\myname{#1}{#2}\label{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\Index{decision tree}{decision trees}
\end{document}
```

If I don't call the `Index` function in the main part, there is no error. But when I call it as in the above example, I get this error:

```
! Use of \@index doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
```

I have very little experience with macros. I know that if I were to use my failing `Index` function
everywhere, then run my Latex document through a Python script that expands the `Index` macro as it should, then compile the resulting expanded Latex source, it would work. So my macro does not expand the way I think it should. I am wondering what is wrong in my code.

**Update: working example**

Here is some stuff that works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, 
                   linkcolor = red]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myname}[2]{#1\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#2}}  
\newcommand{\Index}[2]{\index{\myname{#1}{#2}\label{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The technique presented here, called \ref{bvc}\index{\myname{decision tree!boosted tree}{boosted trees}\label{bvc}}, is used for ...
%The technique presented here, called \Index{decision tree!boosted tree}{boosted trees}, is used for ...
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Now if I replace the line inside the document body by the one commented out (my ultimate goal), that's when I get the compilation error. I suspect the implicitly nested `\newcommand` with a `\renewcommand` is the source of the problem.

Here is that output from the version that works (the one I posted above). On page 1:

[image]

Then on page 2 (the index page):

[image]

What I try to do is treat index entries as if they were equations, for referencing purposes. But the link to an equation is a counter. I want to avoid that and overwrite the counter by the target keyword. So it is equivalent to relabeling.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As always here please make sure your examples are complete. Document class is missing. Additionally you tagged this `hyperref` but none of your examples uses `hyperref`. Thirdly, an error does not appear until one adds `\makeindex`, again this is not in your example. You should probably start by explaining what your end goal is as it is not clear what the combination of `\index` and `\myname ` and `\label` is suppose to be doing here.

Comment: I will work on that and remove the hyperref tag (it started with hyperref but after some improvements, I no longer need it in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how pointing to the index is useful. Anyway…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\newcounter{indexcount}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Index}{mm}{%
  % #1 is index entry; #2 is entry in the text
  \refstepcounter{indexcount}%
  \index{#1@#1\indexlabel{\theindexcount}}%
  \hyperref[index\theindexcount]{#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\indexlabel}{m}{\label{index#1}}

\begin{document}

Some text

\Index{decision tree}{decision trees}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Turns out I actually need \hyperref, on my minimum working example that I will post shortly. The reason to point to the index is as follows: some topics, say 'decision trees', are discussed in multiple chapters on many different pages. A reader encountering 'decision trees' in chapter 3 can click on the indexed keyword, then land on the corresponding entry in the index, find that a sub-keyword listed under 'decision trees' is 'boosted tree' in the index, click on 'boosted tree' subentry in the index, and end up in the page(s) where I discuss 'boosted trees', say in chapter 7.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but not so well with subindex: try \Index{decision tree!boosted tree}{decision trees}. I also need to change the style, but it answers the original question (if you ignore subindex which I did not include initially). Thanks a lot!